# UIScrollView stays in memory while decelerating

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiscrollview, uikit

I noticed a small memory leak issue and I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent it.

If you have a long ScrollView (like TableView) and you swipe down it will keep scrolling for a while before it stops (i.e. inertia).

Now I noticed that if you close the ViewController while the ScrollView is still decelerating the ScrollView won't deinit until it (virtually) stopped scrolling. I noticed that this never takes more than 1 second.

Well no big deal maybe, but still I'm curious if this can be fixed. I tried stopping the scrolling in viewDidDisappear() and many other things but no luck :(.

This issue doesn't seem to apply to iOS 12, but it does to iOS 14 and 15.

Comment: How are you determining this? With a quick test -- nav controller push to VC with scroll view with a content height of 10,000... print `contentOffset.y` on `scrollViewDidScroll`... scroll hard and fast and quickly hit the Back button... scrolling stops (no more `.y` printing) and the VC `deinit` is called as soon as the VC is released - that is, as soon as the "pop" animation ends.

Comment: Yes the VC deinits right-away but the ScrollView stays in memory. Can you try again and monitor the deinit of the ScrollView (instead of the VC)? You can use NSLog() instead of print() to include timestamps in the logs.

Comment: Your post says *"I noticed a small memory leak issue"* ... are you seeing that from Instruments? As far as the delay... quick testing I've seen it take up to 4-seconds for a quick drag on a scroll view to end decelerating. However, either "popping" the VC in a nav controller, or removing the scroll view from the superview and deleting it, the delay until `deinit` is 1-second. So, it's not "waiting until the scroll stops." I assume it is internal UIKit memory management. Unless it's causing a problem, I doubt it's anything to be concerned about.

Comment: I created my own SPM package that detects leaked Views and ViewControllers, called LeakedViewControllerDetector. It pointed out this issue. I noticed the 1 second cap too as you mentioned, but if you swipe more slowly it's sometimes less, so it really acts as a cap. All in all just a bit odd and I know it's not a big deal and I was just curious if there is a way to prevent it.